# Identify dependency provenance for Gradle/Maven builds?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Is there a way to print where my project dependencies are pulled from for a given build ?

Specifically, would like to get this report to determine if jars are coming from an internal repo or upstream maven central.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly capture this at build time with a clean cache/m2 repository, there is not any given command to establish if a dependency is coming from a given source.

Comment: I have ability to do this at build time. Can you elaborate on 'explicitly' capture ? Are you referring to logging to file, and grepping ?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.